# OpenGL GLSL (3.x-4.1) deprecated uniform variables explanation

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, deprecated

I am doing a project involving rendering realistic bubbles using OpenGL using OpenGL 4.1 and GLSL version 410.

In my research I'm discovering that there is a loss of built in OpenGL shader variables/functions between version 3.0 (deprecated) and 3.1 (removed).

This is mentioned in the documentation, and I've concluded that I will have to write these variables myself in my C++ code and pass them into the shaders. I'm just looking for some direction or explanation of exactly what these variables do so that I may get started.

Some variables/functions that I am chiefly concerned about explanation, so that I could begin to rewrite them:

```
gl_TextureMatrix[int n];

vec4 textureCube (samplerCube sampler, vec3 coord [, float bias] );

gl_FragColor;
```

Also, is there an avenue that offers a detailed explanation of these?

Comment: If you're a beginner, you shouldn't be *trying* to replicated the old built-in uniforms. If you don't know what `gl_TextureMatrix` is, then you don't know how to use it either. You should be trying to learn how to use the functionality that OpenGL provides to do what *you* need doing.

Comment: Similar to what Nicol said, you should probably ignore the spec changes if you don't even know why it was changed or where; treat it as history and move on. Are you working with a tutorial? If not, one that helped me with my shaders was [this](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/). I think you will be better off learning how a shader works before learning why things have changed for reasons that are meaningless to you (at the moment). Start small.

Comment: I do know a decent amount. I understand the pipeline, and how a shader works. I am in a class, and we are doing a project and I chose to attempt to model the reflection of a skybox and lighting off of my model which is a sphere which mimics a bubble. So far I have written the code using the old implementation, and I was able to look up great tutorials on reflection and refraction using these variables. However, nothing that I found provided a suitable explanation of how what they are returning is calculated. And I want to support higher versions of OpenGL.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841863/reflection-refraction-with-chromatic-aberration-eye-correction